Undefined reference to 'tputs' when compiling gdb 15 on redhat
I am trying to build gdb15 on redhat, and I get an error:
/usr/bin/ld: ../readline/readline/libreadline.a(display.o): in function `_rl_move_cursor_relative':
/home/myusr/gdb/gdb-15.2/readline/readline/display.c:2805: undefined reference to `tputs'

I get similar ones for tgoto and tgetnum.  I nave ncurses installed, so I'm not sure what the issue is.  If anyone has any advice, I would be very appreciative.
Edit: for more info, I downloaded the gdb-15.2 source, ran
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.12 --enable-targets=all

then ran make.  I was able to get around the problem because the error was on compiling for an architecture I'm not interested in, so, I changed the targets to my preferred architectures (aarch64).  Still curious.

What is the compiler command that leads to this error?

Edited the question with more information.  I forget the architecture and don't want to reproduce it and ruin what I have working.  Something like e2?
